# Debugging SqlException in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a small business web application I'm building in ASP.NET Core 3.1, using EF Core 3.1 as well. There's currently a bug somewhere in the checkout processing that is throwing a SqlException that states the following:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OrderDetails_Orders_OrderId". The conflict occurred in database "BethanysPieShop", table "dbo.Orders", column 'OrderId'.

When I examine the tables in Sql Server Object Explorer, I find that the column OrderId in table dbo.Orders is the Primary Key, and there is the following constraint in the table dbo.OrderDetails:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetails_Orders_OrderId] FOREIGN KEY ([OrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The columns in the dbo.OrderDetails table are as follows:

```
[OrderDetailId] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderId]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [PieId]         INT             NOT NULL,
    [Amount]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [Price]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
```

After doing some research, it seems that the data inserted into the column OrderId in dbo.Orders must be the same as the data inserted into the column OrderId in dbo.OrderDetails. However, I'm not sure how to debug this and examine just what data is being inserted where during runtime. Even if I could manage to find this data, I still wouldn't know how to solve the problem and get rid of the bug anyway, though.

If you need more details or more code, be sure to let me know.

Comment: Your errormessage means, that you try to insert in `orderdetails` with an wrong/not existing `orderid`. Maybe you should look at the order of the code. maybe you try to insert in `orderdetails` before inserting in `orders`. Or maybe you try to save orderdetails and the order object is null. Here is a tutorial on logging with ef core: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx

Comment: I actually found that article and tried it, but the code is obsolete according to the Microsoft documentation and I can't figure out how to debug it to bring it up to date. Some of the APIs have been deprecated or modified, but Microsoft docs aren't always the easiest to understand haha

Comment: Here is the current microsoft docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: So if I use an ILogger instance via dependency injection in the controller where the Checkout method is, will it log the Entity Framework SQL that is run in the background? Because that seems to be the only way that I'll ever see just what data is being inserted into the database tables.

Comment: if everything is configured correctly, you should see the output in the diagnostic tools when you debug the application.